# Spring Oauth and security redirect to /login when login success

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth, single-sign-on

When use Spring security and oauth

I have a problem, when I login in successfully, it redirect to "/login", but I never set it, How can it redirect to the page before login?

follow is details:

auth-center:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: auth-server
server:
  port: 6001
  servlet:
    context-path: /uaa
```

the login page url: /login

follow is the configure

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.antMatcher("/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/403"); 

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login");
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true);
    }
```

client:

```
server:
  port: 4000

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: community
      clientSecret: 123456
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:6001/uaa/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:6001/uaa/oauth/authorize
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:6001/uaa/oauth/user/me
```

follow is the security configure

```java
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("http://localhost:6001/uaa/auth/logout")
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(deniedHandler);

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.httpBasic().disable();
    }
```

when I login successfully, it will redirect to

`http://localhost:6001/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=community&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:4000/login&response_type=code&state=jy2gLx`

but 4000 is client port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the answer,There are some error in application.yml in the client

```
resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:6001/uaa/oauth/user/me
```

the url is wrong

```
resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:6001/uaa/user/me
```

I correct it and it work